# Finding the Posterior Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that the time until a bus arrives is modeled as being equally likely to be $\exp \sim(1.1)$, $\exp \sim(1.2)$, and $\exp \sim (2)$.  The bus actually arrives are time $0.4$.  What are the posterior probabilities for each model?

I figured out that the prior probabilities are $p \sim Unif({1.1,1.2,2})$, but I am not sure how to finish the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Bayes' Theorem:

$$P(M_i | x) = \frac{p(x|M_i) P(M_i)}{p(x)}$$

where $P(M_i) = 1/3$ and $p(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^3 p(x|M_i) P(M_i)$ and $p(x|M_i)$ is given by an exponential with the rate constants you state.

Here we want to calculate $P(M_i|0.4)$.

I find $p(.4) = 0.783213$, which must then be plugged into the above equations.

Comment: Just to clarify, is p(x) =0.4 in this case?

Comment: Since $p(M_1)=p(M_2)=p(M_3)$ you can simplify the ratio to $$ p(M_i\mid 0.4)=\dfrac{p(0.4\mid M_i)}{p(0.4\mid M_3)+p(0.4\mid M_3)+p(0.4\mid M_3)}$$

Comment: Yes you can!...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still a bit confused. As an example for the first exponential rate, why wouldn't it just be [(1.1) * (1/3)] / (0.4) as the probability? @GrahamKemp

Comment: Because, among other things. the (conditional) *probability density functions* for the random variable should be involved in the answer, not *just* the *value* of the random variable.  Here $p(0.4\mid M_1)=1.1\mathrm e^{-1.1 \times0.4}$ et cetera.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I thought that the p(0.4|M1) was simply the exponential rate, so e^1.1

Comment: It is the conditional *probability density function* at $x$ when given event $M_1$ (eg: that the selected rate parameter for the *exponential distribution* is $1.1$).